# ANSI C operating on string which contains '$'

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem: I am trying to do basic operations on string (compare, copy, print to console) passed to a program as an argument. This string contains char '$' ex. "$1$23$45". The problem is that I can't display it properly, the console just shows some random chars - in this case "35" is printed to the screen.

So, I start the program

```
./Lab8Dec $1$23$45
```

which does the following

```
printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

This text is suposed to be printed:

```
$1$23$45
```

But instead this is the result:

```
35
```

Is there any way to treat '$' in variable as a normal character, not as a special one?

Comment: The `$` is interpreted by your shell, try `./Lab8Dec '$1$23$45'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` isn't a special character in C. It is, however, a character indicating a variable in most linux shells. You can protect your input form the shell by using single quotes:

```
./Lab8Dec '$1$23$45'
```